# Google app script not doing everything I want

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

The script i wrote is below. However it is putting the data on sheet tracking and moving down to row 21 instead of 2 and then keeps overwriting 21 instead of moving to 3 then 4. Can someone help me figure out what i did wrong?

function handleButtonBUS() {

insertWordAndTimestamp('BUS');

}

function handleButtonRHD() {

insertWordAndTimestamp('RHD');

}

function handleButtonVEC() {

insertWordAndTimestamp('VEC');

}

function handleButtonQAV() {

insertWordAndTimestamp('QAV');

}

function handleButtonRHD5G() {

insertWordAndTimestamp('RHD 5G');

}

function insertWordAndTimestamp(buttonName) {

var timestampSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Tracking');

var activeRow = timestampSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

if (activeSheet.getActiveCell() === null) {

var activeRow = 2;

} else {

var activeRow = activeSheet.getActiveCell().getRow();

}

var wordCell = timestampSheet.getRange(activeRow, 1);

var timestampCell = timestampSheet.getRange(activeRow, 2);

var currentDate = new Date();

switch (buttonName) {

case "BUS":

wordCell.setValue("BUS");

break;

case "QAV":

wordCell.setValue("QAV");

break;

case "VEC":

wordCell.setValue("VEC");

break;

case "RHD":

wordCell.setValue("RHD");

break;

case "RHD 5G":

wordCell.setValue("RHD 5G");

break;

default:

wordCell.setValue("Unknown Button");

}

timestampCell.setValue(currentDate);

}

Comment: Ref [Issue with an AppScript for Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/247095526). See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone help me figure out what i did wrong?

The issue is with this line:

```
 if (activeSheet.getActiveCell() === null) {
```

That will always get `false`, because you are not retrieving the value in the active cell, but a `Range` object that refers to the cell. It will never be `null`.

To append a row of data at the first completely blank row at the bottom the 'Tracking' sheet, Use [Sheet.appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents), like this:

```
function insertWordAndTimestamp(buttonName) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Tracking');
  sheet.appendRow([buttonName, new Date()]);
}
```